# ImportError: cannot import name 'IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN' from 'secrets'

Tags: python, import, token

I'm facing the above error when I try to execute the following code:

```
from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN
```

I tried using '.secrets' instead of 'secrets' but that gives the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the *secrets library* or anything of such kind.

It's just that after uploading *secrets.py* to the working directory, **restart the kernel in your jupyter notebook**.

Code shall run !!